# The use of "Que" in pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

In most (or many) words that start with the letters "que", there's generally a Kw sound, such as in "question", "queen" or "quest". However, with the word "queue", it's more of a "Ky" sound. Is there any reason for this exception, or is it arbitrary? Are there any other words that also have this "ky" sound, while starting with "que"?

Comment: All these words have been spelt in various ways over the centuries. In Old English, _queen_, for example, was written _cwen_. To answer your question fully would it would be necessary to give a detailed history of the spelling and pronunciation of each word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many borrowings from French often have "qu" denoting /k/ rather than /kw/: *quiche*, *maquette*, then ending *-esque*. However it is true that older borrowings usually have /kw/.

I believe that what is going on here is that the vowel is a rising diphthong /ju/ (like *you*), and the sequence /kwju/ (*qu-you*) was unstable nd became reduced. But I have not looked for firm evidence of this.

Comment: Just to clarify, are the borrowings from French what "queue" probably was, or just an example of an exception?

Comment: @ReliableSource I am by no means certain there was ever a diphthong there.  English *queue* /kju:/ < French *queue* /kø/ < Old French *coue, cue, coe* < Latin *cauda* tail, as in *caudal*.  I don’t know the history or the borrowing, nor do I know anything about the historical French phonology, but it may not have come to us a diphthong.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Yes, it is a borrowing from French, but an old one (Middle English). Words borrowed at that era usually have /kw/ in English (eg _quality_), unlike the recent borrowings I mentioned. As far as I know the diphthongisation of /u/ -> /ju/ is entirely within English, and I didn't mean to suggest otherwise. My suggestion is that at the time when that change happened, the word (previously /kwu/) lost the labial element /w/.